# Why do I have to use the spread syntax in this case?

Tags: javascript, arrays, spread

I'm attempting to solve this leetcode problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/subsets/

Here's the code that works:

```
function subset(set) {
    const result = [];

    helper(set, 0, [], result);
    return result;
}

function helper(set, i, slate, result) {
    if(i === set.length) {
        result.push([...slate]);
        return result;
    }

    // exclude i
    helper(set, i+1, slate, result);
    // include i
    slate.push(set[i]);
    helper(set, i+1, slate, result);
    slate.pop();
}

subset([1,2,3])
```

For this line here:

```
result.push([...slate]);
```

Why is it that when I changed it to `result.push(slate)` or `result.push(...slate)`, neither works even though `slate` itself is an array?

For the case of `result.push(slate)`: Is this because arrays are stored by reference in JavaScript, so when I do  `slate.pop();` here, it also pops out that item that is pushed into the result array?

However, I don't understand the other case (`result.push(slate)`) since it seems that in this case the individual items are pushed in, and not the arrays containing each of those items. Why is that?

Comment: Why don't you do `result = [...result,...slate];` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're indeed right about the first case, but for your second case it so because of the signature of [Array.prototype.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) which is

```
arr.push([element1[, ...[, elementN]]])
```

which is a varargs function (a function that can take an unlimited number of arguments). So when you call

```
// given slate = [1,2,3]
result.push(...slate);
// is the same as calling
result.push(1,2,3)
```

Because your array `slate` is "spread" into individual arguments to `push`. Which will add 1,2,3 as individual array elements to `result`

While calling

```
// given slate = [1,2,3]
result.push([...slate]);
// is the same as calling
result.push([1,2,3])
```

which is correct in your case and will add an array [1,2,3] as a single element to `result`.

Comment: Thank you! Now I'm wondering, since JS is a garbage collector language, do I even need to do `slate.pop` at all?